# Gulp.js - Automatically Upload Views When Altered / Saved

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, gulp, gulp-watch

*tl:dr - Considering my gulpfile.js and CodeIgniter directory structure, can I use the gulp.watch function to monitor a directory for file changes and then upload these files automatically using gulp-sftp without an associated task? If not, is there another technique to accomplish this?*

---

**The Problem:**

I started using Gulp.js for the first time today and I've been able to automate several tasks pretty painlessly by following a [tutorial](https://www.sitepoint.com/introduction-gulp-js/), but unlike the rest of my asset files, I can't seem to find a way to watch and automatically upload my application view files when they are altered.

The major difference is that my watched view directory has no associated task to execute when something changes. If I could come up with a useful task to execute, then my problem would be solved, but I'd rather learn a solution that avoids that entirely - if it exists.

To me, this seems like a problem with a simple solution, but I don't know enough about Gulp's capabilities. Hopefully what I'm describing makes sense. Just in case, I'll provide as much info as possible.

---

**Basic Directory Structure:**

```
mywebsite.com
|
+-- application
|    |
|    +-- controllers
|    +-- models
|    +-- views
|
+-- assets
|    |
|    +-- css
|    +-- images
|    +-- js
|    +-- src
|        |
|        +-- images
|        +-- js
|        +-- scss
|
+-- system
```

**gulpfile.js**

```
// Modules

var gulp = require('gulp'),
    newer = require('gulp-newer'),
    imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin'),
    concat = require('gulp-concat'),
    deporder = require('gulp-deporder'),
    stripdebug = require('gulp-strip-debug'),
    uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
    sass = require('gulp-sass'),
    postcss = require('gulp-postcss'),
    assets = require('postcss-assets'),
    autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer'),
    mqpacker = require('css-mqpacker'),
    cssnano = require('cssnano'),
    sftp = require('gulp-sftp');

// Development Mode?

var devBuild = (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production');

// Folder Aliases

var folder = {
        src: 'assets/src/',
        build: 'assets/',
        app: 'application/' // <-------- Separate Folder Alias
    };

// SFTP Creds

var host = 'webserver.hostingcompany.com',
    user = 'username',
    pass = 'password',
    remotePath = 'mywebsite.com';

// Optimize Images

    gulp.task('images', function() {
        var out = folder.build + 'images/';
        return gulp.src(folder.src + 'images/**/*')
        .pipe(newer(out))
        .pipe(imagemin({ optimizationLevel: 5 }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(out));
    });

// JavaScript Processing

    gulp.task('js', function() {
        var jsbuild = gulp.src(folder.src + 'js/**/*')
            .pipe(deporder())
            .pipe(concat('all.js'));

        if (!devBuild) {
        jsbuild = jsbuild
            .pipe(stripdebug())
            .pipe(uglify());
        }

        return jsbuild.pipe(gulp.dest(folder.build + 'js/'));
    });

// CSS Processing

    gulp.task('css', ['images'], function() {
        var postCssOpts = [
            assets({ loadPaths: ['images/'] }),
            autoprefixer({ browsers: ['last 2 versions', '> 2%'] }),
            mqpacker
        ];

        if (!devBuild) {
            postCssOpts.push(cssnano);
        }

        return gulp.src(folder.src + 'scss/screen.scss')
        .pipe(sass({
            outputStyle: 'nested',
            imagePath: 'images/',
            precision: 3,
            errLogToConsole: true
        }))
        .pipe(postcss(postCssOpts))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(folder.build + 'css/'));
    });

// SFTP Tasks

gulp.task('sftp', function () {
    return gulp.src(folder.src + '*')
        .pipe(sftp({
            host: host,
            user: user,
            pass: pass,
            remotePath: remotePath
        }));
});

// Run Tasks

    gulp.task('run', ['images', 'js', 'css',  'sftp']);

// Watch for Changes

    gulp.task('watch', function() {
        gulp.watch(folder.src + 'images/**/*', ['images']);
        gulp.watch(folder.src + 'js/**/*', ['js']);
        gulp.watch(folder.src + 'scss/**/*', ['css']);
        gulp.watch(folder.app + 'views/**/*.php', ['']); // <-------- The Prospective Watch Function
    });

// Default Task

    gulp.task('default', ['run', 'watch']);
;
```

Comment: You need `gulp-watch` module to work with watch.

Comment: @aslantorret That can't be true because all of the other tasks function properly. Gulp.watch is a built-in function.

Answer (score 1):

If you are new to Gulp, you can take my gulpfile as a base. Now, i don't care about its correctness, just edit this file.

```
'use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp'),
    watch = require('gulp-watch'),
    prefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
    uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
    sass = require('gulp-sass'),
    sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps'),
    rigger = require('gulp-rigger'),
    cssmin = require('gulp-minify-css'),
    imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin'),
    pngquant = require('imagemin-pngquant'),
    rimraf = require('rimraf'),
    browserSync = require("browser-sync"),
    reload = browserSync.reload;


var path = {
build: { //Тут мы укажем куда складывать готовые после сборки файлы
    html: 'build/',
    js: 'build/js/',
    css: 'build/css/',      
    img: 'build/img/',      
    fonts: 'build/fonts/',
    data: 'build/data/'
},
src: { //Пути откуда брать исходники
    html: 'src/*.html', //Синтаксис src/*.html говорит gulp что мы хотим взять все файлы с расширением .html
    js: 'src/js/main.js',//В стилях и скриптах нам понадобятся только main файлы
    style: 'src/style/main.scss',
    img: 'src/img/**/*.*', //Синтаксис img/**/*.* означает - взять все файлы всех расширений из папки и из вложенных каталогов
    fonts: 'src/fonts/**/*.*',
    data: 'src/data/product.json'
},
watch: { //Тут мы укажем, за изменением каких файлов мы хотим наблюдать
    html: 'src/**/*.html',
    js: 'src/js/**/*.js',
    style: 'src/style/**/*.scss',
    img: 'src/img/**/*.*',
    fonts: 'src/fonts/**/*.*',
    data: 'src/data/product.json'
},
clean: './build'
};

var config = {
    server: {
        baseDir: "./build"
    },
    tunnel: true,
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 9000,
    logPrefix: "Frontend_Devil"
};


gulp.task('html:build', function () {
    gulp.src(path.src.html) //Выберем файлы по нужному пути
        .pipe(rigger()) //Прогоним через rigger
        .pipe(gulp.dest(path.build.html)) //Выплюнем их в папку build
        .pipe(reload({stream: true})); //И перезагрузим наш сервер для обновлений
});

gulp.task('js:build', function () {
    gulp.src(path.src.js) //Найдем наш main файл
        .pipe(rigger()) //Прогоним через rigger
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init()) //Инициализируем sourcemap
        .pipe(uglify()) //Сожмем наш js
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write()) //Пропишем карты
        .pipe(gulp.dest(path.build.js)) //Выплюнем готовый файл в build
        .pipe(reload({stream: true})); //И перезагрузим сервер  
});

gulp.task('data:build', function () {
    gulp.src(path.src.data) //Найдем наш product.json файл
        .pipe(gulp.dest(path.build.data))//Выплюнем готовый файл в build
        .pipe(reload({stream: true}));//И перезагрузим сервер
});

gulp.task('style:build', function () {
    gulp.src(path.src.style) //Выберем наш main.scss
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init()) //То же самое что и с js
        .pipe(sass()) //Скомпилируем
        .pipe(prefixer()) //Добавим вендорные префиксы
        .pipe(cssmin()) //Сожмем
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(path.build.css)) //И в build
        .pipe(reload({stream: true}));
});

gulp.task('image:build', function () {
    gulp.src(path.src.img) //Выберем наши картинки
        // .pipe(imagemin({ //Сожмем их
        //     progressive: true,
        //     svgoPlugins: [{removeViewBox: false}],
        //     use: [pngquant()],
        //     interlaced: true
        // }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(path.build.img)) //И бросим в build
        .pipe(reload({stream: true}));
});


gulp.task('fonts:build', function() {
    gulp.src(path.src.fonts)
        .pipe(gulp.dest(path.build.fonts))
});


gulp.task('build', [
    'html:build',
    'js:build',
    'style:build',
    'fonts:build',
    'image:build',
    'data:build'
]);


gulp.task('watch', function(){
    watch([path.watch.html], function(event, cb) {
        gulp.start('html:build');
    });
    watch([path.watch.style], function(event, cb) {
        gulp.start('style:build');
    });
    watch([path.watch.js], function(event, cb) {
        gulp.start('js:build');
    });
    watch([path.watch.img], function(event, cb) {
        gulp.start('image:build');
    });
    watch([path.watch.fonts], function(event, cb) {
        gulp.start('fonts:build');
    });
    watch([path.watch.data], function(event, cb) {
        gulp.start('data:build');
    });
});


gulp.task('webserver', function () {
    browserSync(config);
});


gulp.task('clean', function (cb) {
    rimraf(path.clean, cb);
});


gulp.task('default', ['build', 'webserver', 'watch']);
```

Comment: This will be useful in the future. Thank you. I've read several tutorials on Gulp, but none share your gulpfile variable declaration structure. You seem to have had enough experience with Gulp that you might be able to solve my problem. I think you should give it a try. Feel free to ask me for any additional information if you do attempt to solve it.